# Specific Notifications from Facebook

Tags: android, facebook, api, web-scraping

I was wondering if there is a way to get notifications and content related to only some groups I am a part of in Facebook instead of every post.Does Facebook API offer such functionality? I am looking forward to making a separate application which could only get me notifications and content related to selected groups as I do not want to consume my time over social media.One solution I could approach is by scraping the content and pasting it in my APP news feed.Can someone suggest a better approach? I know the idea seems silly but any help would be appreciated.
PS: I could unlike all the irrelevant pages and stuff but I do not want to do that.

Comment: No there is no API to get notifications

Comment: @WizKid Is there some other way around to achieve the task?

Comment: No there is no other way